# Create multiple page text report in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I am trying to create a SSRS report in SQLServer 2008 r2. The report consist of various pages with lot of static text and few tables in it. The report is around 10 pages long. Can anyone help me on how do i insert page break in text box. Also, if the table inserted is dynamic and can have many rows. Hence I am facing issues of data overlapping on the static text. I want the text box to move down accordingly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying you want a single textbox on the report to span multiple pages?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you want here - can you try to spell it out for those of us who can't see what you're working on?